# CORS for stack.imgur?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, imgur, stack-snippets

Every now and then I happen to come across JS questions that involve canvases and images in some way.
When attempting to answer, I usually create a runnable snippet.
Now, because of [same-origin-policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), any images I use will "taint" the canvas, thus breaking some functionality I sometimes require.
That is, unless I manage to get a [CORS enabled image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image), and here's the point:

On `i.imgur.com`, images **are** CORS-enabled.
On `i.stack.imgur.com` however (which is used for image uploads from the editor), images are **not** CORS-enabled.

---

#### Demo:

`i.imgur.com`:

```js
var i = new Image();
i.crossOrigin = '';
i.onload = function() {
    document.write('Image loaded successfully');
};
i.onerror = function(e) {
    document.write('Error loading image');
};
i.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8e7s.jpg';
```

`i.stack.imgur.com` (only last line changed):

```js
var i = new Image();
i.crossOrigin = '';
i.onload = function() {
    document.write('Image loaded successfully');
};
i.onerror = function(e) {
    document.write('Error loading image');
};
i.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/PORPF.jpg';
```

And just for the record, both images are present:

one:

[image: first image]

and two:

[image: second image]

---

Could this be changed please?
Sure, I could just use "regular" Imgur as a workaround, but then what would be the point of Stack's Imgur account?
And I imagine if anyone can make this change happen, it's the folks at SE, so I'm asking you:

Can `i.stack.imgur.com` please be CORS-enabled?

Comment: No, this shouldn't be changed, since those aren't pictures of unicorns.

Comment: I didn't think it was legal to host non-cat-based images on imgur. Perhaps that's the issue here?

Comment: @Won't [There](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R76N0.jpg). Unicorns, cats, blood, fire and rainbows for you folks. Now give me CORS. :(

Comment: IE doesn't support that based on MDN and I don't want to be left out... and I fail to understand why you can't use a `data:image/base64;...` for this purpose? Strangely enough both of your example show *Image loaded successfully* so now I'm even more confused...

Comment: @rene I tried base64, but there's a character limit of 30'000 characters per post, and the base64 version of the deer image above is alone 35178 characters. The rest of the post in which I wanted to use that image is a bit more than 6000 characters, so sure, I could've searched for a smaller image too, but it was a question about image rotation, so small images kinda suck, and in that case I could've just gone with regular Imgur (as I did in the end). Also, when trying to insert a base64 blob into the editor again now, my tab constantly crashes. I kinda like links, they're somewhat shorter...

Comment: @rene as for both loading, IE probably just ignores the whole thing. It's like the unpopular kid left alone, while the cool kids play with the cool stuff. (IE browser, I mean ;))

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, IE just works (just verified with the developers tools and network panel open...)

Comment: @rene yes it works, but it doesn't support those cool features discussed here. (the snippet does not use them)

Comment: @ShadowWizard  :((((

Answer (score 12):

As a temporary work-around you can use a proxy for the `i.stack.imgur` images. Using http://cors.io works in the example below.

```js
var i = new Image();
i.crossOrigin = '';
i.onload = function() {
    document.write('Image loaded successfully with: "' + i.src + '"');
};
i.onerror = function() {
    i.src = 'http://cors.io?u=' + i.src;
    i.onerror = function() {
        document.write('Error loading image');
    }
};
i.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/PORPF.jpg';
```

Comment: @Won't Please actually use the snippet to determine if it is runnable or not before removing the snippet controls. I am well aware of the difference between code formatting and snippets.

Comment: Ugh, I completely botched that one. My bad.

Comment: Treasure this moment, @Tiny - I've never seen Mr. Won't apologize before. ;)

Comment: Hmm I get error loading image with this, but not with the original images...

Comment: @TinyGiant Chrome 46.0.2490.80 and I see this: http://imgur.com/DXskcLG

Comment: @TinyGiant my bad, it was blocked by a spam filter that didn't show the error message in the snippet. Sorry :/

Comment: This fails with `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://cors.io/?u=https://i.stack.imgur.com/PORPF.jpg. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).` on Firefox 56.

Comment: Even this solution seems to have been broken now

Comment: Whoever ran the Heroku app on that webpage isn’t running it anymore.